# C++ File output and cout differ

Tags: c++

I've tried to solve finding the minimum time to print a string if all the letters of the alphabet (A-Z) form a circle:

- The printer starts at A.
- You can go left to right or right to left.
- The next letter is printed from where you left off.

[image]

**Example for string "BCY"**:

Going counter-clockwise here to find the minimum time. The total minimum time will be 6 seconds:

- A to B takes 1 second
- B to C takes 1 second
- C to Y takes 4 seconds

**Code**

The inputs are an integer C that tells you which subtask to solve, and 2 strings S and T. T is only relevant for the second subtask. The output for the first task is just the minimum time required to print the string.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("circular.in");
ofstream fout("circular.out");

bool dh (char a) {
    return a - 'A' > 12;
}
int64_t calc_min(char a, char b) {
  int64_t add = 0;
  if(dh(a) == dh(b)) {
    add = abs(a - b);
  }
  else if(dh(a) != dh(b) && dh(a) == false)
    add = min((a - 'A') + ('Z' - b) + 1, b - a);
  else if(dh(a) != dh(b) && dh(a) == true)
    add = min((b - 'A') + ('Z' - a) + 1, a - b);
  return add;
}


int main() {
  int c;
  string s, t;
  fin >> c >> s >> t;

  int64_t times = (dh(s[0]) ? 'Z' - s[0] + 1 : s[0] - 'A');
  for(unsigned i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
    times += calc_min(s[i], s[i - 1]);

  fout << times << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**Problem**

The correct output is 324479. The string in test case 6 has 50000 characters but pasting 50000 characters into the console yields "26588". Pasting it into "circular.in" gives the correct answer.

If I use cin.tie && sync_with_stdio both set to false, the console bugs out with strings that are >= 800 characters, see test case 4.

[Circular Problem stackoverflow on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fz4JQ3y7) (if you'd like to solve both subtasks). The only difference between File Input/Output and Console Input/Output is in test case 6, see https://pastebin.com/v2HeGL74

Is it normal because the string is too big or is there another reason?

Comment: Can your terminal handle dumping 50K characters all at once? Many of them have input limits to prevent <expletive deleted> heads trying to overflow buffers or perform other malicious acts. Perhaps your input is being truncated at 32k (max 16 bit signed integer) or smaller.

Comment: Running Windows, I think you're right honestly. Searched on the internet and found this: "A little bit of google later, and I learn that Windows has a 32767 character command line limit. That limit is even less, 8191, if trying to execute the process from within cmd.exe."

Comment: You can confirm with `string::size`. If `s` and `t` are smaller than the right size, the input got lopped off.

Comment: Hey, I just [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71534173/revisions) your post as a result of trying to understand the scenario. Feel free to revert/modify my changes, especially in the problem description part at the end.

Comment: @Christian Much more readable thanks to you!

Comment: @cezar you're welcome. I love writing and editing is much easier than starting from the scratch. Interesting problem though.

Comment: @cezar that's the limit of a command you run, not the limit on what a command outputs

Comment: @phuclv I was inputting 50000 characters (wasn't referring to the output). Since I inputted more characters than the terminal could support, my program was calculating the answer for the first 32.7k

Comment: @Christian solved both subtasks, it was indeed terminal limit. ios::sync_with_stdio(0) works well if you're using file input, although I don't know if the instruction really matters when working with files.